# Data Extension CSV export not working correctly

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, csv

I'm currently transferring some data from an old BU that's being depreciated to a new one. As part of this I've recreated a data extension and am now attempting to export the data from the previous/existing DE and import it into the new DE.

I'm having an issue exporting the data successfully - Marketing Cloud seems to be introducing additional line breaks into the output CSV file, which causes hundreds of invalid field count errors. The field that's causing the issue has data typically of a format like:

```
[Coke Energy Video Banner - 1200x1200px MP4 Consumer ,Coke Energy Web Banner - 205x235px GIF Business,Coke Energy Video Banner - 946x1080px MP4 Consumer,Coke Energy Web Banner - 300x600px JPG Business]
```

Which gets exported as:

```
[Coke Energy Video Banner - 1200x1200px MP4
Consumer
,Coke Energy Web Banner - 205x235px GIF
Business,Coke Energy Video Banner - 946x1080px MP4
Consumer,Coke Energy Web Banner - 300x600px JPG
Business]
```

The '[]' are part of the data.

I have tried exporting with several different delimiters (comma, tab and an arbitrary character (£)) and have the same issue each time.

Does anyone know what causes the SFMC to insert additional linebreaks and what I can do to prevent it from doing so?

ETA Additional Info: 
The file has not been opened in any program between being exported and being imported. The fields are exactly the same in both data extensions - save for one 'field length' value, but I'm pretty sure it's not the problem.

Below is an anonymized snippet from the log. You can see it's registering one record as five separate parts, causing a bunch of invalidfieldcount errors:

```
Row Number  Error Number    Error Code  Error Details   Row Data
0   1987450525  InvalidFieldCount   Invalid Field Count [Redacted][Redacted][Redacted@live.co.uk][Redacted][Redacted][Redacted][True][True][[Coke Energy Video Banner - 1200x1200px MP4]
1   1987450526  InvalidFieldCount   Invalid Field Count [Consumer]
2   1987450527  InvalidFieldCount   Invalid Field Count [,Coke Energy Web Banner - 205x235px GIF]
3   1987450528  InvalidFieldCount   Invalid Field Count [Business,Coke Energy Video Banner - 946x1080px MP4]
4   1987450529  InvalidFieldCount   Invalid Field Count [Consumer,Coke Energy Web Banner - 300x600px JPG]
5   1987450530  InvalidFieldCount   Invalid Field Count [Business]][30/05/2019 06:23:06][ecf4d29c-b21b-406f-8c90-059ce508bcb8]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96532/discussion-on-question-by-666lumberjack-data-extension-csv-export-not-working-co).

Comment: Please [edit] the body of this question post with all relevant clarification and details.

Comment: Hi @666lumberjack, I got the same issue recently. Do you have any insights/updates on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using the example text from above, I was able to successfully import into a test data extension by using a delimiter of |. 
I was also able to successfully import by adding quotations to the field as text qualifiers and selecting the option for text qualifiers on the import.